# php install dompdf without composer

Tags: php, installation, server, dompdf

i'm trying to install the library Dompdf on product server without good results.

I use php 7.4 and i can't use composer.
I followed the instruction found on gitHub page, i downloaded the version 2.0.1 with all dependencies. Then i moved on project folder, but when i try to launch an example like this doesn't work.

```
<?php
   require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
   use Dompdf/Dompdf;
   $dompdf = new Dompdf();
?>
```

The only error that i obtain is:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

the folder struct is this:
phpfiles
dompdf:
vendor:
autoload.inc.php

Can anyone explain me how to include the library without install composer in the server?
Thank You.

Comment: Apart from php7.x, please make sure you have `html5-php v2.0.0 or greater, php-font-lib v0.5.4 or greater, php-svg-lib v0.3.3 or greater` in your system

Comment: @KenLee thanks you for your suggestion, how can i verify if these libraries are present? because the instruction on github says they were present in the full version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the source code and import it in your code, here is the link
[link to dompdf lib](https://%20https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases)

Comment: Hi @Issam, I did exactly that, but it doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: @leogamer2222 - did you ever resolve the issue?